# Electron Muon Scattering

Tags: particle-physics, metric-tensor, quantum-electrodynamics

I have been doing studying in advance for Dirac Equation and stumbled upon the math on calculating the spin-averaged amplitude $\bar{M}^{2}$ for the electron muon scattering process. Below is an example of how it was done, but I want to understand the math behind defining the dot product $P_i \cdot P_j$.
[image: Example]

I have no problem in expanding the last terms on red as I got them to be working by using the fact that $g_{\mu \nu} g^{\mu \nu} = 4$. My concerns are all about the other cross terms and I am finding it difficult to follow. At some point, I can see that I also need to use the fact that $g_{\mu \nu}p^{\nu} = p_{\mu}$. What I am skeptical about is doing the expansion, for example the first term.

$\left(P^{\mu}_{C}P_{A}^{\nu}\right)\left(P_{D \mu} P_{B \nu}\right) = P^{\mu}_{C} P_{D \mu} 
P_{A}^{\nu}P_{B \nu} = (P_C \cdot P_D)(P_A \cdot  P_B)$

Is it correct that I can just move around $P_i$ as I please?

Comment: The components of those momentum four-vectors are just numbers, so they commute.

Comment: @Ghoster Aight. I got everything to be working right now. Thanks for confirming!